# Heroku fails to load page. MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I been trying to upload my app to Heroku But I keep getting this MongoError: authentication fail error.  I have both username and password correctly. Can someone help me out. I tried installing different version But no use.

running `mongod --version`

```
db version v3.4.4
git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
```

In my package.json I have

```
"dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^4.4.12",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.2"
  },
```

> app.js
>
> ```
> var mongoose = require('mongoose');
> mongoose.connect('<username>:<password>@ds129023.mlab.com:29023/ng2');
> ```

```
 heroku logs:-

        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
         MongoError: Authentication failed.
         at Function.MongoError.create (/app/node_modules/mongodb-
          core/lib/error.js:31:11)
         at /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:497:72
           ^
         at authenticateStragglers (/app/node_modules/mongodb-
          core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:16)
         at Connection.messageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb-
         core/lib/connection/pool.js:477:5)
         at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-
         core/lib/connection/connection.js:321:22)
          at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
          at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
          at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
          at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
          at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing protocol name here

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds129023.mlab.com:29023/ng2');
```

I added mongodb before username. Try with this, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Make sure that you've created a user for your database

[image]

For case with "admin" user, it could be:
mongoose.connect('mongodb:admin:@ds129023.mlab.com:29023/ng2');

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in my case I have not added config vars in Heroku app.
Go to Heroku website > Your App > Settings > Reveal Config Vars  and add your environment variables there.
[As You Can see in the following image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1gpb.png)